# when spark can throw out of memory exception

Tags: apache-spark

I have an input data with size 216GB(more than 3000 .gz files). I have to store this data into a partitioned hive table. Partition is done via a column say X. There are 40 distinct X columns. I wanted a single file per partition. So loaded the hive table with below code.

```
df.repartition(df.col("X")).write.partitionBy("X").parquet("/path/to/table")
```

This is causing OOM exception.

The same code works fine for a data with size 293GB(a single csv file) and 187 distinct X columns.

Can anyone help me with exactly what is happening here?

The number of records coming in for a single value for column X is quite different between the two. For example, in the first case 40 million records are coming for a single value of X and in second case, its around 5 million.

Can I exactly find at what point, it can throw OOM exception?

Comment: Share the sample data for df

Comment: sample data has around 25 columns. 3 columns are string and rest are decimal. I cannot post the exact data here.